# Understanding Generics in ResultWrapper Class - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, covariant

I am currently trying to grasp the usage of the [ResultWrapper class](https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/how-to-handle-errors-with-retrofit-and-coroutines-33e7492a912) in Kotlin, specifically focusing on its generic implementation. The class is defined as follows:

```
sealed class ResultWrapper<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val value: T): ResultWrapper<T>()
    data class GenericError(val code: Int? = null, val error: ErrorResponse? = null): ResultWrapper<Nothing>()
    object NetworkError: ResultWrapper<Nothing>()
}
```

By what I understood,T is the response model we are expected to receive in case of Success.In case of Generic or Network Error we dont receive the Success Response Model and hence we used Nothing which is the subclass of all classes and represents a value that never exists.To support `ResultWrapper<Nothing>` we made T covariant here as making it covariant will make `ResultWrapper<Nothing>` a subtype of `ResultWrapper<T>` an hence can be used as return value in safeApiCall.I hope that's correct!

However, I am puzzled about the necessity of making Success a covariant subclass. Since Success always has the success response model T, and not its subtype, why is out T used in the declaration:

```
data class Success<out T>(val value: T): ResultWrapper<T>()
```

Additionally, since T is covariant, it can only be used in output positions (i.e., as a return type), but how is it possible for `safeApiCall` to use T as a parameter?

```
suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher, apiCall: suspend () -> T): ResultWrapper<T> {
    return withContext(dispatcher) {
        try {
            ResultWrapper.Success(apiCall.invoke())
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            when (throwable) {
                is IOException -> ResultWrapper.NetworkError
                is HttpException -> {
                    val code = throwable.code()
                    val errorResponse = convertErrorBody(throwable)
                    ResultWrapper.GenericError(code, errorResponse)
                }
                else -> {
                    ResultWrapper.GenericError(null, null)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first paragraph is correct.

The superclass needs `out` for that Nothing “trick” to work. And nothing in this hierarchy of classes consumes `T` so even if we weren’t using `<Nothing>`, we would want to increase the flexibility of the class by relaxing the variance.

Variance makes classes less restrictive to use, not more restrictive. It does make  defining the class’s own function and property signatures more restrictive, for the benefit of making the class more useful to the code outside it.

It also makes the signature of the class more descriptive, which is an improvement for code readability and understanding.

I’m not sure I understand your last question because your `safeApiCall` only has `ResponseWrapper<T>` in the return (out) position so it obviously is fine to use it there. Maybe your are confusing the `T` of the function with the `T` of the ResponseWrapper class, but these are two completely different things. Try renaming it something other than `T` in the function and maybe it will help you see what’s going on.

```
 suspend fun <X> safeApiCall(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher, apiCall: suspend () -> X): ResultWrapper<X> {
```

The function here has its own generic type `X`. Functions’ generic types are always invariant since there is no need for variance—you don’t cast functions. (Well if we were talking about functional objects, this would get more complicated.) `X` is an input to the function and if you called this function with a lambda and without explicitly giving the type, the compiler would implicitly use the output type of the lambda to infer what `X` is. Then the function returns a `ResponseWrapper` whose generic type is `X`. So `X` is being passed to ResponseWrapper to be used for its `out T`. It is a ResponseWrapper that can produce X’s (at least in the Success case). The covariance of ResponseWrapper isn’t helping us here, but at the call site it could be helping with implicit upcasting, for example.

Comment: `It would create an illogical condition if Success declared its type to be invariant but as the candidate for the superclass’s covariant type.`
Even if i remove `out` from success , my project is compiled and run successfully.Superclass `out` is to support Nothing but in Success we know that exact T type will be received.so why to broaden  the type parameter?

Comment: Oh, you’re right. It will compile. Adding “out” only helps in places where you might be working directly with a Success type and want to implicitly upcast its result type. Not a very common scenario but “out” does make it theoretically more flexible and describes the class’s behavior better.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could share an example with a code snippet where `out T` in `Success` can help!

Comment: The situation is rare and it would take a bunch of code to try to create an example. You would need to have an hierarchy of result types that you want to handle together as a group for some reason. I personally would never do this. But I’d still mark the type `out` because there’s no good reason not to. It better describes the class behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am puzzled about the necessity of making Success a covariant subclass.

It's not necessary. Removing *out* from `Success` is still fine. You cannot make it contravariant though by using *in*, that would prohibt you from declaring `value` (because as a property it is in an *out* position) and extending `ResultWrapper` (it only allows *out* types).

If `Success` had a method that would take a parameter of type `T`, then you would have the need for both *out* and *in*, so you wouldn't declare either:

```
data class Success<T>(val value: T) : ResultWrapper<T>() {
    fun doSomethingWithAnotherT(other: T) {}
}
```

This wouldn't clash with the *out* from `ResultWrapper`, though: If you look at `Success` as a `ResultWrapper`, you wouldn't see `doSomethingWithAnotherT`, since it doesn't exist in `ResultWrapper`. `Success` would entirely conform to the *out* from its parent.

> Since Success always has the success response model T, and not its subtype, why is out T used in the declaration

Since there is no method `doSomethingWithAnotherT` in `Success`, there is no need to broaden the type parameter and it can be confined to *out*. So the answer would be: "Why not." But maybe you are confused by something else: The type parameter `T` from `ResultWrapper` is different to the type parameter `T` from `Success`. They actually have no connection at all, you can even rename one of them to something else like `R`, for example. It *looks* like they would be the same by how closely they are declared to one another, but they aren't, and I actually would strongly recommend *not* to use the same name so they cannot be confused so easily.

Now, since they are separate type parameters you can also separately declare their variance (*in* or *out*), you just have to honor the inheritance (as stated above, an *in* type cannot inherit from an *out* type).

> Additionally, since T is covariant, it can only be used in output positions (i.e., as a return type), but how is it possible for `safeApiCall` to use T as a parameter?

The parameter in question, `apiCall`, does not have the type `T`, it has the type `suspend () -> T`. That's a huge difference, beause a `T` is never passed to anything, it is only returned from the *function* `apiCall`. Therefore `T` only appears in the *out* position and can be safely used the was it is.

Comment: `Since there is no method doSomethingWithAnotherT in Success, there is no need to broaden the type parameter and it can be confined to out. `
But Variance makes classes less restrictive to use, not more restrictive.so out is indeed broadening the type parameter.

Comment: `The parameter in question, apiCall, does not have the type T, it has the type suspend () -> T. That's a huge difference, beause a T is never passed to anything, it is only returned from the function apiCall`

Even though if i pass T as a parameter,compiler will not complain about same.Like:
`suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,test : T, apiCall: suspend () -> T): ResultWrapper<T>`
But if i create function inside ResultWrapper with T as parameter compiler will complain.Why?

Comment: I think you’re mixing up two different applications of generics—class declaration site generics and function declaration site generics. See the last part of my answer. If you declared this `safeApiCall` function inside your result wrapper, the `<T>` in its signature would be hiding the `T` of the class and actually have nothing to do with it so it would compile but be ill-advised because of the confusing use of T for two different things. If you then removed `<T>` from the function signature, it would suddenly be referring to `T` of the class and be violating the variance—an error.